# unable to load asset [flutter]

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I tried yesterday to put an image and it was working just fine but when I tried to run it again it gave me this error:

```
Restarted application in ٢٬٧٦٥ms.

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════[39;49m
[38;5;244mThe following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:[39;49m
Unable to load asset: cat.jpg

[38;5;244mWhen the exception was thrown, this was the stack[39;49m
[38;5;244m#0      PlatformAssetBundle.load[39;49m
[38;5;244m<asynchronous suspension>[39;49m
[38;5;244m#1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync[39;49m
[38;5;244m<asynchronous suspension>[39;49m
[38;5;244m#2      AssetBundleImageProvider.load[39;49m
[38;5;244m...[39;49m
[38;5;244mImage provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "cat.jpg")[39;49m
[38;5;244mImage key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#7533e(), name: "cat.jpg", scale: 1.0)[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m
```

and here is the yaml:

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - images/cat.jpg
```

and in main

```
child: Image(
  image: AssetImage('cat.jpg'),
),
```

so what's the problem here?

Comment: Oh sorry , I did now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change this code :

```
child: Image(
   image: AssetImage('cat.jpg'),
),
```

into this one :

```
// add the full reference of the image
child: Image(
   image: AssetImage('images/cat.jpg'),
),
```

**if this won't work** for you then try to move your images folder inside lib folder and change your references like this :

**inside yaml :**

```
flutter:
   uses-material-design: true
   assets:
      - lib/images/cat.jpg
```

**inside your dart code :**

```
//the full reference of the image
child: Image(
   image: AssetImage('lib/images/cat.jpg'),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

you must give **full path** into Image Widget like declared in your **pubspec.yaml**

```
child: Image(
  image: AssetImage('images/cat.jpg'),
),
```

appended your **images** file is in your app top level directory like this

```
->(Your_App_Name)
  ->images
   ->cat.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Add full path in Main file.

```
Image(
   image: AssetImage('images/cat.jpg'),
),
```